# I am getting KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\Desktop\depremleri-goruntuleme-main\main.py", line 15,
> in 
> for item in json["result"]: KeyError: 'result'

im getting this keyerror error and I don't know how to solve it

```
import json
from os import system
from time import sleep
import requests                                 
from colorama import init, Fore
init(autoreset=True)

while True:

    print(Fore.RED+"            5 1 2 4 - O f f i c a l \n")
    print(Fore.RED+"Tür         "+Fore.CYAN+"Tarih & Saat           "+Fore.GREEN+"Yer           "+Fore.RED+"Büyüklük        "+Fore.YELLOW+"Derinlik")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    json = requests.post("https://api.orhanaydogdu.com.tr/deprem/live.php").json()
    for item in json["result"]:
        tarih = item["date"]
        yer = item["lokasyon"]
        büyüklük = item["mag"]
        derinlik = item["depth"]

        print(Fore.RED+"Deprem ! "+Fore.CYAN+tarih+Fore.GREEN+" "+yer+Fore.RED+" "+str(büyüklük)+Fore.YELLOW+" "+str(derinlik)) #Depremleri yazdırıyoruz

    sleep(13)
    system("cls")
    sleep(0.6)
```

Comment: that's because in the json that the request returned there's no key named `result`

Comment: This code will be trying to read the data in the json. I would suggest getting a copy of the json to find what key you mean?

Comment: You should find and read the documentation of the API.

Comment: i checked the json and there is a key named "result"

Comment: `json` is the name of a module. You should not be naming your variable `json`

Comment: You don't need `import json` if you're using the `.json()` method of `requests`.

Comment: Use `print(json)` to see what the result is. If it's large, use the `pprint` module to print it more readably.

Comment: Maybe the "result" key is in a sub-dict inside the `json` dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your complete code, I just replaced post with get method.

```
import json
from os import system
from time import sleep
import requests                                 
from colorama import init, Fore
init(autoreset=True)

while True:

    print(Fore.RED+"            5 1 2 4 - O f f i c a l \n")
    print(Fore.RED+"Tür         "+Fore.CYAN+"Tarih & Saat           "+Fore.GREEN+"Yer           "+Fore.RED+"Büyüklük        "+Fore.YELLOW+"Derinlik")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    json_data = requests.get("https://api.orhanaydogdu.com.tr/deprem/live.php").json()
    for item in json_data ["result"]:
        tarih = item["date"]
        yer = item["lokasyon"]
        büyüklük = item["mag"]
        derinlik = item["depth"]

        print(Fore.RED+"Deprem ! "+Fore.CYAN+tarih+Fore.GREEN+" "+yer+Fore.RED+" "+str(büyüklük)+Fore.YELLOW+" "+str(derinlik)) #Depremleri yazdırıyoruz

    sleep(13)
    system("cls")
    sleep(0.6)
```